# How to redirect to https with Spring cloud gateway & ribbon

Tags: spring, ssl, spring-cloud, ribbon

I have 2 microservices working with https, I added spring cloud gateway api to centralize the routes but I faced a problem where it says: `This combination of host and port requires TLS` I'm pretty sure that's because of the routes configuration on my gateway, I dont have much experience on this side but if someone could help me.

this is my spring gateway routes configuration :

```
  @Bean
  public RouteLocator gatewayRouter(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
    return builder.routes()
        .route(p -> p.path("/api/v1/**")
            .uri("lb://statement"))
        .route( p -> p.path("/api/v3/**")
            .uri("lb://activiti-workflow"))
        .build();
  }
```

Please I just want to know if this configuration will redirects to https or not, because while sending http requests directly to the microservices it works but with gateway is doesn't.

Comment: If you are using eureka, you can set the secure port. Otherwise you can use `lbs://`

Comment: I used  `lbs://` on each uri the error is gone returns 200 but no data just blank. securing the ports I don't know too much about that can you reference that ? thanks in advance spence

Comment: I can't help without more information

Comment: Also, please note that Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon is no longer maintained and its dependencies are not being upgraded. We strongly recommend using Spring Cloud LoadBalancer instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your backend services in eureka provide https, your can set route uri like this:

```yaml
uri: lb:https://your-service-name
```

Or

```java
.uri("lb:https://your-service-name")
```

It just like websocket configuration. The key class is `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter`

More info see at: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#the-routetorequesturl-filter

If your backend services use insecure HTTPS cert, your may need config this:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        ssl:
          useInsecureTrustManager: true
```

See at: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#tls-and-ssl